# Can we capture IPv6 packet using Socket.BeginReceive

Tags: c#, sockets, ipv6

We have developed a small program to analyse the notwork packet of a flash application using System.Net.Sockets.Socket, it works fine in most cases, but suddenly one of my client reported that the application does not work.  After investigation, it was found that there has no packet received in her workstation.

The design of our program obtained the list of local IPs from Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList, and then monitor the traffice for each ipAddress as below,

```
Socket monitor_Socket;

IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 0);
monitor_Socket = new Socket(ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Raw, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.IP);
monitor_Socket.Bind(ipe);

monitor_Socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, BitConverter.GetBytes((int)1), null);
monitor_Socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(this.OnReceive), null);
```

And the packet will be handled in the callback funciotn OnReceive.

We have tested in almost all computers in our office, it works fine, and we can't guess what happen to this client's machine.  We have make a small program using FiddlerCore to capture the http packet in her workstation to verify the flash application, and it can capture the data as expected, that mean the communication is OK.  However, it just can't capture the packet using our application as above.  She is a computer layman, and she can't tell us any special setting in her workstation.

After studying the msdn document, it seems that we have overlooked something in IOControl, and we don't know if this is the cause of problem.

According to the information in msdn (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.iocontrolcode.aspx), the ReceiveAll means "Enable receiving all IPv4 packets on the network", does it mean that it will not receive IPv6 packets?

Unfortunately, we can't find any IOControlCode is used for IPv6.  And we guess this may be the problem if she is using IPv6.  But we cannot verify at this moment, and we don't want to bother her too much before we have any possible solution.

We'd like to confirm if the BeginReceive in above code can work with IPv6.  If not, how can we capture the packet of IPv6 using Socket?    If this is not the cause of problem, is there any other situation that the Socket cannot capture the http packet?

We understand that FildderCore can be used in this case, and our first version was developed using FiddlerCore.  But unfortunately, as FiddlerCore run as a system proxy, it will cause problem if the application crashed.  The proxy setting cannot be restored, and all network communication will be failed.  It's hard to ask our client to remember how to resume the network in this case, and they cannot reach our support via the network.  So, to avoid such situation, we decided not to use system proxy for capturing in this case.  And we also hope that our application can be done without third party library.

Comment: Will it help to change the ProtocolType to `System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.IPv6`?

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Maybe we can try this first.  
I have checked my workstation have both IPv4 and IPv6  ip address,  Do you know how can we force to use IPv6 only in our workstation for testing?

Comment: I found something about `DualMode` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.dualmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot.  That really confusing.  When we create the socket object, we already specified the AddressFamily, in this case, it should already defined if the socket is used for IPv4 or IPv6, I can't understand what it mean by those other setting for IPv4 or IPv6.  For the ProtocolType setting, it seems that IP is unspecified, which will follow the socket setting.

Comment: After reading more information in IPv6, it seems that it's not as simple as I think to have the IPv6 connection, and my client may not using IPv6.  As our program is capturing the packet to a target host, and it can't have IPv6 connection from client side where the server does not support.  We have to think about other possible cause of issue.

Comment: Mostly firewall issues